# Reset position in dragended event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to reset the position of a group if it's not dragged in the dropzone.

It works but when I try to drag it a second time, the group moves back to where it was dragged at first.

I think it's related to the origin.

Here's my code and a  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t67onzog/2/)

```
   function init(){
       var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                    .origin(function (d) { return d; })
                    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("dragend", dragended);

       entities = svg.selectAll("g")
                     .data([{ x: 750, y: 100 }])
                     .enter()
                     .append("g")
                     .attr("class","entity-group")
                     .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
                     .attr("initial-x", function (d) { return d.x })
                     .attr("initial-y", function (d) { return d.y })
                     .call(drag);
   }

   function dragstarted(d) {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        d3.select(this)
          .classed("dragging", true);
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;

        d3.select(this)
           .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" });
    }

    function dragended(d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .classed("dragging", false);

        if (d.x > dropzoneWidth) {
            var entity = d3.select(this);
            var x = entity.attr("initial-x");
            var y = entity.attr("initial-y");

            entity.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")"; });
        }
    }
```

I have also tried this

```
d3.behavior.drag()
           .origin(function (d) {
                   var t = d3.select(this);
                   return {
                            x: d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[0],
                            y: d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[1]
                        };
                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `+=` in your drag handler.  I'd use [d3.mouse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_mouse) against the parent container:

```
function dragged(d) {
    var coors = d3.mouse(this.parentNode);
    d.x = coors[0];
    d.y = coors[1];

    d3.select(this)
       .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" });
}
```

---

Full Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    var dropzoneWidth = 200;
    
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500)
    
    
      function init(){
       var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                    .origin(function (d) { return d; })
                    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("dragend", dragended);

       entities = svg.selectAll("g")
                          .data([{ x: 100, y: 100 }])
                          .enter()
                          .append("g")
                          .attr("class","entity-group")
                          .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
                          .attr("initial-x", function (d) { return d.x })
                          .attr("initial-y", function (d) { return d.y })
                          .call(drag);
                          
                        entities
                          .append('circle')
                          .style('fill', 'black')
                          .attr('r', 15)
   }

   function dragstarted(d) {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        d3.select(this)
          .classed("dragging", true);
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        var coors = d3.mouse(this.parentNode);
        d.x = coors[0];
        d.y = coors[1];

        d3.select(this)
           .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" });
    }

    function dragended(d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .classed("dragging", false);

        if (d.x > dropzoneWidth) {
            var entity = d3.select(this);
            var x = entity.attr("initial-x");
            var y = entity.attr("initial-y");

            entity.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")"; });
        }
    }
      
      init();
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense but It makes the top left corner jump to the mouse. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t67onzog/3/

Comment: Is there a way to reset the d.x and d.y in the dragged function in dragended?

Comment: @Marc The problem is it sets the position of the `g` by translate (which is the upper left corner).  You want to drag by the `g` with respect to the mouse position in the rect: http://jsfiddle.net/t67onzog/4/